# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called when CloudKit record is added

Tags: ios, notifications, cloudkit

**What I want:**

I want my iOS app to perform an action once an CloudKit record is added.

**What I did:**

I followed Apple's [info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html) to do this.

**Problem:**

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` is never called.

**What I tried to solve the problem:**

I've successfully set up a subscription to get notified when an CloudKit record is added. I confirmed this with `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.

I've also confirmed that the record is indeed created.

I can fetch the record using `CKQueryOperation`.

I've also tried it with `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`, but this method is also not being called.

I've searched the Apple Developer Forums as well as StackOverflow but did not find a solution to my proble.

What can I do?

Code to create the subscription:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];

    CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"command" predicate:predicate options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation];


    CKNotificationInfo *notificationInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
    notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = @"New command.";
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = YES;

    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo;

    [VMKGlobalVariables.GLOBAL_appDelegate.privateDatabase saveSubscription:subscription
                   completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
                       if (error)
                       {
                           // insert error handling
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           DDLogVerbose(@"Added command subscription successfully.");
                       }
                   }

     ];
```

Comment: Remote notification doesn't work on a simulator. You need to use a real device. Is this the case?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I use an iPhone 6s.

Comment: Update your question with more relevant information about the subscription and the added record. And confirm that you are talking about adding the record on one device and getting the notification on a second device. You won't get a notification on the same device used to add the record.

Comment: I've added the code for adding the subscription. The command record is created on a Mac and is supposed to be received on my iPhone. I confirmed that the record was actually created: when I fetch all command records on my iPhone, I can read it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register you app delegate with the line.

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Did you have some code look like this in your app delegate?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let notification = CKQueryNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as! [String : NSObject])

    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.blah.com")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase

    if notification.notificationType == .Query {
        let queryNotification = notification as! CKQueryNotification
        if queryNotification.queryNotificationReason  == .RecordUpdated {
            print("queryNotification.recordID \(queryNotification.recordID)")


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I registered for remote notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `shouldSendContentAvailable`.

```
let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = info
```